# Consuming message from Tibco EMS with Quarkus

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, tibco-ems, mutiny

I'm working with a Quarkus application where I need to consume messages from Tibco EMS and then process these messages. Below is the snippet of my current implementation:

```
Session session = connection.createSession();
Destination destination = session.createQueue(configurationProperties.queueFlight());
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

consumer.setMessageListener(message -> {
  FlightData flightData = flightDataConverter.toFlightData(message);
  // TODO: send to kafka
});
```

This code is part of a method that's called at the start of the Quarkus application. It successfully receives messages from Tibco EMS. However, my goal is to enhance this process by implementing a reactive approach, possibly using Mutiny.

I'm seeking advice on whether it's possible to refactor this code to a reactive model with Mutiny, and if so, how I might go about it. Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: reactive-messaging-jms is not fully integrated with Quarkus. See also: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/30943

Comment: @Serkan, given that reactive-messaging-jms is not fully integrated with Quarkus as highlighted in the issue, is it possible to manually implement a reactive messaging system using Quarkus, Vert.x, and Mutiny? If so, could you suggest some resources or provide guidelines on how to get started?

Comment: There is already a smallrye-reactive-jms implementation, but somehow this doesn't work with Quarkus. I think you can ask this question in their Zulip chat channel, and most probably Clement can help you with it.

See smallrye-reactive-jms:
https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/4.12.0/jms/jms/

See Zulip chat channel:
https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users